# Finding the function that corresponds to a Fourier series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, zeta-functions

Im trying to reverse engineer a Fourier series that came about in my work by happenstance. The series in question:
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{c}{c^{2}+(2n+1)^{2}}\sin((2n+1)x)-\frac{2n+1}{c^{2}+(2n+1)^{2}}\cos((2n+1)x)
$$
The sum in question only needs to be valid on $x\in [0 , t] , t < \pi$, so it may correspond to not necessarily periodic function. The series is very close to a kind of triangle wave if it weren't for c. You may also notice that the coefficients correspond to the Laplace transform's: $\mathscr{L}\{ \sin(ct)\}(2n+1) , \mathscr{L}\{ \cos(ct)\}(2n+1)$ (for the respective function). This seems like it could be leveraged but I have been unsuccessful in doing so. Another avenue I have persued is expressing it in terms of the [Lerch-Zeta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function) fuction as follows.
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Re}\bigg(e^{ix}\zeta\bigg(\frac{x}{\pi},1,\frac{1}{2}(1-ic)\bigg) \bigg)
$$
(Edited because it was incorrectly the imaginary part)
But this seems like a very heavy piece of mathematical machinery for a series such as this. I have tried to find lists of known Fourier series but haven't seen it apear in those lists. Any help you can provide on any potential leads would be great, Thank You!

**Addition**:

After working the problem for a bit one addition I can make is the following expression is equivalent to the series above.

$$
\frac{e^{-cx}}{2}\operatorname{Re}\bigg(\psi\big( \frac{1-ic}{2} \big) \bigg)-e^{-cx}\operatorname{Im}\bigg(\int^{x}_{0} te^{ct}\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{ \ln\big(\Gamma\big( \frac{1+is}{2} \big)\big)  \}(t) dt \bigg)
$$

This was found by taking the Laplace transform of the Lerch-Zeta function, which then produced a series that could be represented with [Digamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_representation) functions. I then took the inverse Laplace transform of this expression using known properties of the Laplace transform. However, now the problem can be characterized by trying to find the inverse Laplace transform of either the Digamma function or the Log-Gamma function on the $\operatorname{Re}(z)=1/2$ line of the complex plane. I have been unable yet to find such an expression. I have an inkling that it may involve the Jacobi-Theta function and Modular Forms by looking at different expansions of the Digamma/Log-Gamma functions, but haven't been able to over-come some domain conditions and nuances regarding Laplace transforms and complex logarithm's. Again any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to

$$f_c(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{c}{c^2+(2 n+1)^2} \sin((2 n+1) x)-\frac{2 n+1}{c^2+(2 n+1)^2} \cos((2 n+1) x)\right)\tag{1}$$

Mathematica simplfies

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{c}{c^2+(2 n+1)^2} \sin((2 n+1) x)\tag{2a}$$

to

$$g_c(x)=$$ $$\frac{1}{8} \left(e^{-i x} \left(\Phi\left(e^{-2 i x},1,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i c}{2}\right)-\Phi\left(e^{-2 i x},1,\frac{1}{2} (1+i c)\right)\right)+e^{i x} \left(+\Phi\left(e^{2 i x},1,\frac{1}{2} (1+i c)\right)-\Phi\left(e^{2 i x},1,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i c}{2}\right)\right)\right)\tag{2b}$$

where $\Phi(z,s,a)$ is the [Hurwitz–Lerch transcendent](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HurwitzLerchPhi.html) and

Mathematica simplifies

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty -\frac{(2 n+1) \cos ((2 n+1) x)}{c^2+(2 n+1)^2}\tag{3a}$$

to

$$h_c(x)=$$ $$\frac{1}{8 c} i e^{-i x} \left(\left(e^{2 i x}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i c}{2}} \left(\left(e^{2 i x}\right)^{i c} \left(B_{e^{2 i x}}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i c}{2},0\right)+2 B_{e^{2 i x}}\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{i c}{2},-1\right)\right)-B_{e^{2 i x}}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i c}{2},0\right)-2 B_{e^{2 i x}}\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{i c}{2},-1\right)\right)+\left(e^{-2 i x}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i c}{2}} \left(\left(e^{-2 i x}\right)^{i c} \left(B_{e^{-2 i x}}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i c}{2},0\right)+2 B_{e^{-2 i x}}\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{i c}{2},-1\right)\right)-B_{e^{-2 i x}}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i c}{2},0\right)-2 B_{e^{-2 i x}}\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{i c}{2},-1\right)\right)\right)\tag{3b}$$

where $B_z(a,b)$ is the [Euler beta function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Beta.html?q=Beta).

---

Therefore $f_c(x)$ defined in formula (1) above can be evaluated as

$$f_c(x)=g_c(x)+h_c(x)\tag{4}.$$

---

I believe $f_c(x)$ can also be represented as the inverse Laplace transform

$$f_c(x)=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{H_{\frac{1}{2} i (c+i)}+H_{-\frac{1}{2} (1+i c)}-H_{\frac{1}{2} i (i+s)}-H_{-\frac{1}{2} (i s+1)}}{4 (c+s)}\right](x)$$ $$=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty} \frac{H_{\frac{1}{2} i (c+i)}+H_{-\frac{1}{2} (1+i c)}-H_{\frac{1}{2} i (i+s)}-H_{-\frac{1}{2} (i s+1)}}{4 (c+s)}\, e^{x s} \, ds\tag{5}$$

where $H_s$ is the analytical Harmonic number function.

---

Formula (5) above follows from simplification of the term-wise Laplace transform of formula (1) for $f_c(x)$ above, and formula (5) above leads to the alternate representation

$$f_c(x)=$$ $$\frac{i \left((-c+i)\, e^{i x} \, _2F_1\left(1,-\frac{1}{2} i (c+i);-\frac{1}{2} i (c+3 i);e^{2 i x}\right)+(c+i)\, e^{-i x} \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{2} (1+i c);\frac{1}{2} (3+i c);e^{-2 i x}\right)\right)}{2 \left(c^2+1\right)}\tag{6}.$$

where $_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ is the [Hypergeometric2F1 function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric2F1.html?q=Hypergeometric2F1)

Comment: If you work it out all of these combinations the Beta function and Horowitz-Lerch transcendent simplify to that expression with the Lerch-Zeta function. It doesn't really answer the question though because it's still fundamentally in the form of a Fourier-Transform because all of these simplify to series of sines and cosines.

Comment: @AidanR.S. I don't believe the Lerch-Zeta expression in your question is equivalent to your initial sum, but I posted another representation of your sum in formula (6) in my answer above which is perhaps closer to your desired representation.

Comment: You are right that the Lerch-Zeta expression was wrong it should have been the real part and not the imaginary part. Other then that though if you multiply out $\frac{1}{2n+1-ic}e^{i(2n+1)x}$ then factor out a $\frac{-1}{2}$ it become the Lerch-Zeta function.

Comment: In regards to the hypergeometric series if you use the Gamma Function definition of the Pochhamar symbols and then use the definition of the Gamma Function you again just recover the Lerch-Zeta function.

Comment: @AidanR.S. So all derived representations can be shown to be equivalent which is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: yes in a way, but all said expressions are in one way or another still the same Fourier series. The goal to hopefully find a a representation that isn't in the form of a sum of sines and cosines.

Comment: @AidanR.S. Perhaps the reason all derived representations can be translated to a sum of sines of cosines is because the function is only currently defined as a Fourier series which is periodic. But if you're looking for a non-periodic function associated with your defined Fourier series here are a few observations. I believe the function $g_c(x)=f_c\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-f_c\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ is an odd function of $x$ (at least for $-\frac{\pi}{2}<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$), $g_c(x)$ has poles at $x=\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $g'_c(0)=0$ when $c\approx 1.24502$.

Comment: Some of those properties I was able to attain another interesting property I found was that is that the series equals $\frac{1}{2}ln|tan(x/2)|$ when $c=0$. Thank you for all the work you've put into this though I may have to accept that a representation in the form of my liking may not be findable.

Comment: Also for $c=0$, the Lerch-Zeta representation simplifies to $f_0(x)=-\Re\left(\tanh^{-1}\left(e^{i x}\right)\right)$, and your original Fourier series and formula (6) in my answer above both simplify to $f_0(x)=-\frac{1}{2} \left(\tanh^{-1}\left(e^{i x}\right)+\coth^{-1}\left(e^{i x}\right)\right)$.